# Correct way to unit test Express Middleware

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, express, mocha.js, chai

I have a piece of Express middleware that is set to check for a valid Content-Type header in all of my POST requests that hit my server, the code for this middleware is below:

```
import * as STRINGS from "../Common/strings";

function ContentTypeValidator(req, res, next) {
    let contentHeader = req.get("content-type");
    if(!contentHeader) {
        res.status(400).send(STRINGS.ERROR_CONTENT_TYPE_MISSING);
    } else {
        if(contentHeader.toLowerCase() !== "application/json") {
            res.status(415).send(STRINGS.ERROR_CONTENT_TYPE_UNSUPPORTED);
        } else {
            next();
        }
    }
}

export default ContentTypeValidator;
```

I am using `mocha`, `chai` and `node-mocks-http` for my TDD and my question surrounds the tests when `next()` will not be called as `res.send()` will handle the ending of this request for me.

```
it("Should return 200 for valid Content-Type header", (done) => {
    req = nodeMocks.createRequest({
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
    });
    ContentTypeValidator(req, res, (err) => {
        res.statusCode.should.equal(200);
        expect(err).to.be.undefined;
        done();
    });
});

it("Should return 400 if Content-Type header is missing", (done) => {
    ContentTypeValidator(req, res, () => {});
    res.statusCode.should.equal(400);
    res._getData().should.equal("Content-Type header missing");
    done();
});
```

In the first test above, I am expecting this to pass, so I pass in a function to act as the `next()` function and this test passes. In the second test, I am expecting this to fail so if I pass in a function then mocah complains that the test has exceeded 2000ms as the callback function is never called, which is to be expected since `res.send()` is handling it in this instance.

Is the way I've written the second test correct when it comes to unit testing Express middleware like this or is there a better/more advisable way to do this?

EDIT: So just to clarify, I am focused on wanting to test the middlewear when the next callback will NOT be called, the question I'm apparently duplicating is looking at using `sinon` to check if next is called. I am looking to see how to unit test when the callback function will NOT be called.

Comment: I have edited the question to show how it is different from the question I am apparently duplicating.

Comment: can you use sinon to spy on the res function? e.g. 

`var res = {statusCode: sinon.spy()};`

then try 

`(res.statusCode).should.equal(500)`

Answer (score 15):

Check out this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34517121/4996928

```
var expect = require('chai').expect;
var sinon  = require('sinon');

var middleware = function logMatchingUrls(pattern) {
    return function (req, res, next) {
        if (pattern.test(req.url)) {
            console.log('request url', req.url);
            req.didSomething = true;
        }
        next();
    }
}

describe('my middleware', function() {

  describe('request handler creation', function() {
    var mw;

    beforeEach(function() {
      mw = middleware(/./);
    });

    it('should return a function()', function() {
      expect(mw).to.be.a.Function;
    });

    it('should accept three arguments', function() {
      expect(mw.length).to.equal(3);
    });
  });

  describe('request handler calling', function() {
    it('should call next() once', function() {
      var mw      = middleware(/./);
      var nextSpy = sinon.spy();

      mw({}, {}, nextSpy);
      expect(nextSpy.calledOnce).to.be.true;
    });
  });

  describe('pattern testing', function() {
    ...
  });

});
```

Comment: I had actually seen that one, but that answer seems more focused on using `sinon` to check that `next()` is actually called. In my instance I can't call next since the response will be rejected before it's called.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BwNMUVzo3vs