# Testing a basic middleware of expressJS

Tags: javascript, express, integration-testing

There is a very basic middleware, which I would like to test.

First question is what kind of test I'm using. For my understanding, I cannot write a unit test for this code.
I would call that an integration test. Is that correct?

The second problem ist the test itself: I'm running into a timeout, althoug I've used `done()`.
What am I doing wrong? And is that the correct way to test this middleware?

**/middlewares/graphql.js**

```
module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With')
  if (req.is('application/graphql')) {
    req.body = { query: req.body }
  }
  if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    res.sendStatus(200)
  } else {
    next()
  }
}
```

**/tests/middlewares/graphql.js**

```
import nodeMocks from 'node-mocks-http'
import middleware from '../middlewares/graphql'

describe('GraphQL middleware', () => {
  it('Should return 200 for valid Content-Type header', (done) => {
    const req = nodeMocks.createRequest({
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/graphql'
      },
      body: {
        content: 'anything'
      },
      method: 'OPTIONS'
    })
    const res = nodeMocks.createResponse()
    middleware(req, res, (err) => {
      expect(res.statusCode).toEqual(200)
      expect(res.body.content).toEqual('anything')
      expect(err).toBeNull()
      done()
    })
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`middleware` is a function with `(req, res, next)` as parameters. You send `req`, `res` and a callback where you handle the assertions. I.e. the assertion testing is passed in as `next()`.

But there is no reason for `next()` to be called when you pass in `OPTIONS` as request method. The middleware will then do `res.sendStatus(200)` instead. So you have to call middleware as an ordinary function instead (for this particular test).

```
middleware(req, res);

expect(res.statusCode).to.equal(200);
expect(res.body.content).to.equal('anything');
done();
```

It will fail on the except for `res.body`, but that's because the middleware function is written that way.

As long as you only test the middleware function I would call it unit testing. If you care about what happens after `next()` gets called I would call it integration testing. But what it's called is not that important as long as it's tested.

You can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34517121/8574934) answer for testing when the middleware has to call `next()`.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. There is only one thing left for this issue: body is undefined, although I'm setting it in `createRequest`. Also `res._getData()` is an empty string.

Comment: @user3142695 You are setting `req.body` in the test. Do you want `res.body` to be non-empty? Then you have to return that in the middleware.

Comment: Oh. That's a misunderstanding on my side... How do I handle `if (req.is('application/graphql')) { req.body = { query: req.body } }` in my test? Where do I have to set `'application/graphql'`?

Comment: @user3142695 That's the req.headers['Content-Type'] you set it in the test. `req.is()` reads that header. You set it correctly from what I can see. Testing that you change req.body when graphlql is used is not very easy. I would maybe put the stuff inside the if in a separate function and have a test for that too.